# Show status code description depending on the current status code

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have an application that is going to be used to change the status code of production units to track them throughout the process.  My current issue is displaying the status code description depending on the status code of the currently selected record.  I have a method that I think will do the job, but I do not know where to put it to perform the desired actions.  I have a 2NF Microsoft Access (.mdb) database on the backend that has all of the desired information and is built properly, but I am having trouble working with it through C#.

```
 public void DescLabel()
{
    if (statusCodeLabel.Text == "-5")
    {
        statusCodeDescLabel.Text = "Problem with Unit.";
    }

    if (statusCodeLabel.Text == "10")
    {
        statusCodeDescLabel.Text = "Manufacturing Order Created.";
    }

    if (statusCodeLabel.Text == "15")
    {
        statusCodeDescLabel.Text = "Stock Room in Process.";
    }

    if (statusCodeLabel.Text == "20")
    {
        statusCodeDescLabel.Text = "Picked by Stock Room.";
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to attach an event handler to a relevant event. Probably `statusCodeLabel.TextChanged` or `statusCodeLabel.Leave`

Comment: It's better to store codes as binary, for example 0110 which first bit(MSB) is _Problem with unit._, second bit is related to _Manufacturing Order Created._ and so on.
You're not forced to use bit like this, you can think decimal. I mean 8(1000) is _Problem with unit._ and 12(1100) is both of _Problem with unit._ and _Manufacturing Order Created._.

Comment: what is this application? WPF, or Win form, or Web? if it's WPF, write a value converter, bind the value to the label of another control, i.e. Label. Also, from clean code perspective, put the code/description in a hashtable, which read from an external file

Comment: You say its based on the "status code of the currently selected record". So however you are navigating through records, whether its buttons or a drop down list, you'd put it in the appropriate change events for that control. Also, I'd use a `Dictionary<int, string>` to store the codes and values, or better yet, a database.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply add a property to your Production Unit model class, called StatusDescription and have it return the strings above based on its internal status code. Then, just call that property from your UI to get the text you desire.

```
public StatusDescription {
    get {
        if (statusCode == 15) {
            return "Stock Room in Process.";
        }

        // etc, etc.

        return string.Empty;
    }
}
```

Then just...

```
statusCodeLabel.Text = productionUnit.StatusDescription;
```

And update your UI when it is required to be updated. Either on a change of state. Or on a timer, whatever your application requires.

That said, it's something that sounds like it should be in the database already and mapped to your model class via the status code in question.